# How can I compile this program?

Tags: java, deque

I have a problem with compilation of this program  I don't know how can I  solve this problem

```
class ArrayTester{

    public void arrayTester(ArrayDeque arrayDeque) {

        List evenlist = new ArrayList();
        List oddlist = new ArrayList();

        for (int n = 0; n < arrayDeque.size(); n++) {

            if (arrayDeque.Length() % 2 == 0) {
                arrayDeque.addAll(evenlist);
            } else {
                arrayDeque.addAll(oddlist);
            }

            System.out.println(evenlist);
            System.out.println(oddlist);
        }
    }
}

class Kodilla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayDeque<String> arrayDeque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        String text = "";
        int howLong = random.nextInt(50) + 1;
        while (text.length() < howLong) {
            text = text + "a";
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                arrayDeque.add(text);
                System.out.println(arrayDeque);
                System.out.println(arrayDeque.size());

                arrayTester tester = new ArrayTester();
                tester.arrayTester(arrayDeque);
                System.out.println(arrayTester);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we are humans, not compilers. it would greatly help if you post the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

what I see is that in this line
`arrayTester tester = new ArrayTester();`
there is typo in the variable definition.  (lowercase a)

Comment: I want to separate into even and odd 'a' Strings generated with random by counting all of these and sort to the two arraylist's but compiler won't show me any of this 'a' Strings